# try catch orm doctrine on symfony3.3 syntax

Tags: php, try-catch, symfony-3.3

I am trying to Catch Doctrine exception in the controller by try catch, i am using Symfony 3

```
try {
   $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
   $em->persist( $transaction );
   $em->flush();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'already exist']);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... and what's happening? What *isn't* happening? What do you want to happen?

Comment: I wanna catch the exception that will happen ex: EntityAlreadyExist , UniqueConstraint , the code hat i past on my question don't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly i got the solution for my problem and i wanna share the solution with you

```
try {
   $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
   $em->persist( $transaction );
   $em->flush();
} catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(409, "Transaction already exist" );
        } catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConstraintViolationException $e ) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(409, "Bad request on Transaction" );
        } catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException $e ) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(409, "Transaction Table not found" );
}
```

This link contains all Exception in Doctrine

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Exception